# Is there such a thing as an http shell?

Tags: shell, http, command-line

I'll soon be doing a presentation on the basics of HTTP for colleagues where I work.

I've done this sort of thing a number of times, and one thing I like to do is telnet directly to an http server and send the various headers that way. The idea is to show the simplicity of the protocol, and remove browsers from the discussion.

In the past, I've used a text document to copy the headers from because of typos and timeouts. So, it goes something like this:

- telnet to somewebserver.com:80
- For the first go, simply type in GET, etc. This emphasizes the fact that it's simple, just text, etc.
- For later requests copy and paste the request from a text document.
- Etc...

It would be nice if there was a way to replay previous commands, similar to the way various shells' history works. However, searching for http [interactive] shell is a bleak wasteland of irrelevance.

Does such a thing exist? Or am I off base in my search terms? Any advice is welcome, including suggestions about other tools or tips for building my own.

I'll likely be doing the presentation on a Macintosh.

Thanks!

Greg

Comment: I doubt something like that exists, simply because there is no need for a _raw_ interactive communication with a http server. What I _could_ imagine to be possible though is to use a standard shell and open a socket to the http server. Then you can simply redirect any term you like to that socket.

Comment: rlwrap... and netcat?

Comment: Yeah, just thought of `kermit`, but then indeed `netcat` came to my mind too.

Comment: I've voted to close as asking for an off-site resource, but I actually have one: http://http-prompt.com/

Comment: @BenjaminW. Heh. Thank you!

Comment: @arkascha Exactly. I mean, I agree that my use case is pretty exotic.

Thanks for the idea, though. Just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is based on @BenjaminW's.

HTTPie appears to do what I want.

https://httpie.org/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use [PostMan](https://www.getpostman.com/), I've used it to develop RESTful APIs for several years, it can send any kind of http request, sync your browser's cookie, I think it's also a great tool to manage your http request.

Comment: Nice but a bit overweight for this use case. OTOH, worth looking at for day-to-day work. Thanks!